# SceneKit -– How to get animations for a .dae model?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, maya

Ok, I am working with ARKit and SceneKit here and I am having trouble looking at the other questions dealing with just SceneKit trying to have a model in `.dae` format and load in various animations to have that model run - now that we're in iOS11 seems that some solutions don't work.

Here is how I get my model - from a base `.dae` scene where no animations are applied. I am importing these with Maya -

```
var modelScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ryderFinal3.dae")!

if let d = modelScene.rootNode.childNodes.first {
    theDude.node = d
    theDude.setupNode()
}
```

Then in Dude class:

```
func setupNode() {
    node.scale = SCNVector3(x: modifier, y: modifier, z: modifier)
    center(node: node)
}
```

the scaling and centering of axes is needing because my model was just not at the origin. That worked. Then now with a different scene called "Idle.dae" I try to load in an animation to later run on the model:

```
func animationFromSceneNamed(path: String) -> CAAnimation? {
    let scene  = SCNScene(named: path)
    var animation:CAAnimation?
    scene?.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes({ child, stop in
        if let animKey = child.animationKeys.first {
            animation = child.animation(forKey: animKey)
            stop.pointee = true
        }
    })
    return animation
}
```

I was going to do this for all my animations scenes that I import into Xcode and store all the animations in

```
var animations = [CAAnimation]()
```

First Xcode says `animation(forKey:` is deprecated and This does not work it seems to (from what I can tell) de-center and de-scale my model back to the huge size it was. It screws up its position because I expect making the model move in an animation, for example, would make the instantiated model in my game snap to that same position.

and other attempts cause crashes. I am very new to scene kit and trying to get a grip on how to properly animate a `.dae` model that I instantiate anywhere in the scene -

1. How in iOS11 does one load in an array of animations to apply to their SCNNode?
2. How do you make it so those animations are run on the model WHEREVER THE MODEL IS (not snapping it to some other position)?

Comment: having exactly the same problem, I have also tried to load the animation using SCNSceneSource but it doesn't work. Please let me know if you find any solution

Comment: Does .dae format even include animations?  I Have you tried using Alembic (.abc) for that?

Answer (score 1):

At first I should confirm that `CoreAnimation` framework and some of its methods like `animation(forKey:)` instance method are really deprecated in iOS and macOS. But some parts of `CoreAnimation` framework are now implemented into `SceneKit` and other modules. In iOS 11+ and macOS 10.13+ you can use `SCNAnimation` class:

```
let animation = CAAnimation(scnAnimation: SCNAnimation)
```

and here `SCNAnimation` class has three useful initializers:

```
SCNAnimation(caAnimation: CAAnimation)
SCNAnimation(contentsOf: URL)
SCNAnimation(named: String)
```

In addition I should add that you can use not only animations baked in `.dae` file format, but also in `.abc`, `.scn` and `.usdz`.

***Also, you can use [SCNSceneSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenesource) class (iOS 8+ and macOS 10.8+) to examine the contents of a `SCNScene` file or to selectively extract certain elements of a scene without keeping the entire scene and all the assets it contains***.

Here's how a code with implemented `SCNSceneSource` might look like:

```
@IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
var animations = [String: CAAnimation]()
var idle: Bool = true

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sceneView.delegate = self

    let scene = SCNScene()
    sceneView.scene = scene
    
    loadMultipleAnimations()
}

func loadMultipleAnimations() {

    let idleScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/model.dae")!
    
    let node = SCNNode()
    
    for child in idleScene.rootNode.childNodes {
        node.addChildNode(child)
    }       
    node.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -5)
    node.scale = SCNVector3(0.45, 0.45, 0.45)
    
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
    
    loadAnimation(withKey: "walking", 
                sceneName: "art.scnassets/walk_straight", 
      animationIdentifier: "walk_version02")
}
```

...

```
func loadAnimation(withKey: String, sceneName: String, animationIdentifier: String) {

    let sceneURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: sceneName, withExtension: "dae")
    let sceneSource = SCNSceneSource(url: sceneURL!, options: nil)

    if let animationObj = sceneSource?.entryWithIdentifier(animationIdentifier, 
                                                 withClass: CAAnimation.self) {
        animationObj.repeatCount = 1
        animationObj.fadeInDuration = CGFloat(1)
        animationObj.fadeOutDuration = CGFloat(0.5)

        animations[withKey] = animationObj
    }
}
```

...

```
func playAnimation(key: String) {

    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addAnimation(animations[key]!, forKey: key)
}
```

Comment: Hi Andy, Pls tell from where did get "walking" and "walk_version02" names?